# Workaround for x:Shared in Universal Applications

Tags: .net, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I have a Style setter that sets the value to a resource.

It works for a single element, but when the Style is applied to more than 1 element, an exception is thrown. This is what I have:

```
<SymbolIcon x:Key="Star" Symbol="Star" />


<Style TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Star}"/> 
</Style>
```

I understand that only one  instance will be created. Since I cannot create "multi-instance" resources , how could I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make couple elements, not only one instance, then you can use templates. A simple example:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Star">
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Favorite"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource Star}"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ContentControl/>
        <ContentControl/>
        <ContentControl/>
        <ContentControl/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]