# How Can I Reuse an Icon in Resources in UWP? In WPF, I'd use x:Shared=false

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to create a button `Style` that I can use for a "Lookup" button throughout my UWP app. However, the icon only appears on the first button on the screen. I tried [this solution using templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33388126), but it is not working for me. Thanks for the help.

Code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="FindSymbolTemplate">
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Find" Foreground="White" />
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="LookupButton">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContentControl Template="{StaticResource FindSymbolTemplate}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
....
<Button x:Name="tourNumLookup"
       Style="{StaticResource LookupButton}"
       Grid.Column="1"
       Margin="10,0"
       VerticalAlignment="Center" />
....
<Button x:Name="customerIdLookup"
       Style="{StaticResource LookupButton}"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       Grid.Column="1"
       Grid.Row="1"
       Margin="10,0" />
```

The two buttons in the UI. Only the first has the `SymbolIcon` content.

[image]

Comment: Why not to use `ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FindTemplate}"` with `<DataTemplate x:Key="FindTemplate"><SymbolIcon Symbol="Find" Foreground="White" /></DataTemplate>` ?

Comment: This worked for me. If you submit this as an answer, I will mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally UI elements can be used once (or saying different - have only one parent) - this is probably why it only works for the first button in your case. One solution may be to define *DataTemplate* and use it as *ContentTemplate*, so each button creates its own icon:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FindTemplate">
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Find" Foreground="White" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
...
<Button x:Name="tourNumLookup" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FindTemplate}"
        Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<Button x:Name="customerIdLookup" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource FindTemplate}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0" />
```

Answer (score 3):

@Romasz's solution absolutely works, but what if you want a lightly different `Foreground` on the `SymbolIcon` inside another `Button`?

Here's a potentially more flexible way that I normally go with.

First let's create a *base* `Style` that holds some default values for all the icons.

```
<Style x:Key="Style-Icon-Base"
       TargetType="ContentControl">
    <!-- If you don't specify the Foreground, it will use its ancestor's -->
    <!--<Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="White" />-->
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="0" />
</Style>
```

Then we create a new icon `Style` which inherits from the one above. Note within the `ControlTemplate` I have used `TemplateBinding` to make property values *dynamic*. `TemplateBinding` isn't available inside a `DataTemplate`.

```
<Style x:Key="Style-Icon-Find"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource Style-Icon-Base}"
       TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <!-- 
                    'cause you cannot change the size of the SymbolIcon, we insert a Viewbox here, 
                    otherwise you don't need it. 
                -->
                <Viewbox Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                         HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                         VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Find"
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                </Viewbox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This way you have created a highly reusable icon `Style`, to use it, have a look at the following `Button`s:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Margin="4"
            Padding="8"
            BorderBrush="LightBlue">
        <ContentControl Width="36"
                        Height="36"
                        Foreground="DarkCyan"
                        Style="{StaticResource Style-Icon-Find}" />
    </Button>

    <!-- Note how I defined the Foreground at the Button level and it flows down to the icon -->
    <Button Foreground="DarkGoldenrod"
            Margin="4">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource Style-Icon-Find}"
                            Width="16"
                            Height="16" />
            <TextBlock Text="Search"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="8,0,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>

    <Button Margin="4"
            Padding="4">
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource Style-Icon-Find}" />
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And they look like:

[image]

Comment: I must say that I really like your answers, even if they compete with mine ;).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create `ControlTemplate` to reuse the icon. You can simply put this `SymbolIcon` to the resource dictionary and use as `StaticResource` for the buttons' `Content`.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SymbolIcon x:Key="FindSymbol" Symbol="Find" Foreground="White" />
</Page.Resources>

<Button x:Name="tourNumLookup"
        Content="{StaticResource FindSymbol}"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="10,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
<Button x:Name="customerIdLookup"
        Content="{StaticResource FindSymbol}"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="10,0" />
```

**UPDATE**

BTW this is possibly a **bug** in the UWP platform, because I tried the following code and only the first `Button` rendered the icon at desing time and none of the at runtime.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SymbolIcon x:Key="FindSymbol" Symbol="Find" Foreground="White" />
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="LookupButton">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource FindSymbol}"/>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="tourNumLookup"
            Style="{StaticResource LookupButton}"
            Margin="10,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <Button x:Name="customerIdLookup"
            Style="{StaticResource LookupButton}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="10,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

I tried to assign the `Setter`'s `Value` directly but I got the same result. And also tried with `FontIcon`.

Comment: I, too, had issues with the code you suggested. Another user submitted a working approach as a comment on my question. Thanks for the input!